# Get SSL certificate files from private key

Tags: ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate, private-key

I want to get crt & a chain file from a private key. the file I have is starting with

> -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----

& an extension of .key file.

tried multiple ways to convert it using OpenSSL command but not getting it properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is impossible to get certificate and chain from the private key. While one can get the public key from the private key file, the public key is part of the certificate. In addition to the public key it also contains subject, expiration, issuer and issuers signature - the last two needed to build and verify the trust chain.

Comment: okay, you mean I have to create a public key from the private key, then using private & public key combination i can create a crt file ?

Comment: @chhameed: You can create many certificates with a public key. But these will not be a publicly trusted certificate, i.e. clients will reject such a certificate unless it is explicitly added as trusted to these clients. If you need a publicly trusted certificate some public CA need to sign it and for this you need to prove that the subject of the certificate (i.e. usually a domain) is owned by you.

Comment: yes i have a private key from public CA (ionos one & one), they only provide me a private key. now my question is how i can create a crt file & a chain file from a private key

Comment: @chhameed: You don't get a private key from a public CA. The private key should be created locally and kept secret. I think you get the whole process of how to create a certificate wrong. But how to create a certificate (either self-signed or a public one) is not actually what you've asked for, i.e. your original question is answered with a clear "impossible".

Comment: thanks for your help. contacted to CA for other cert files. got the files & it is working now.

Answer (score 1):

Just having a private key does not provide the certificate associated with that key.

The certificate contains a lot of information that the mere private key does not, including validity dates, subject and signer DNs, SANs, usages, along with the cryptographic signature itself.